# How to stop reading from channel on error?

Tags: go

I want to stop reading from the channel once an error is encountered. I think I need to use errroup.WithContext() but I can't quite wrap my head around how to integrate it.

Here is the output:

```
Thread 2: STARTED
Thread 1: STARTED
Thread 0: STARTED
Thread 2: GOT=0
Thread 1: GOT=1
Thread 0: GOT=2
Thread 0: FAILED
Thread 1: GOT=3
Thread 2: GOT=4
Thread 2: GOT=5
Thread 1: GOT=6
Thread 1: GOT=7
Thread 2: GOT=8
panic: Thread 0: FAILED
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    const threads = 3

    ch := make(chan int, threads)

    eg := errgroup.Group{}

    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        i := i
        eg.Go(func() error {
            fmt.Printf("Thread %d: STARTED\n", i)
            for n := range ch {
                fmt.Printf("Thread %d: GOT=%d\n", i, n)
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
                // Simulate failed thread
                if n == 2 {
                    fmt.Printf("Thread %d: FAILED\n", i)
                    return fmt.Errorf("Thread %d: FAILED", i)
                }
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }

    close(ch)

    if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

.....................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`errroup.WithContext()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#WithContext) is probably the best approach (as you guessed). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247219/11810946) is worth reading; it provides a comprehensive explanation (which I will not attempt to replicate!).

However as this can be difficult to understand here is one solution using your code ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DLdkcpuDdhO)):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    const threads = 3

    ch := make(chan int, threads)

    eg, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(context.Background())
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        i := i
        eg.Go(func() error {
            fmt.Printf("Thread %d: STARTED\n", i)
            for n := range ch {
                fmt.Printf("Thread %d: GOT=%d\n", i, n)
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
                // Simulate failed thread
                if n == 2 {
                    fmt.Printf("Thread %d: FAILED\n", i)
                    return fmt.Errorf("Thread %d: FAILED", i)
                }
                // For the purpose of this example we will just check the context after
                // doing the work.
                if ctx.Err() != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Thread %d: Quiting due to context\n", i)
                    return fmt.Errorf("Thread %d: Context cancelled: ", i)
                }
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    // We want to stop sending new work if there is a failure (otherwise `ch <- i` will block permanently);
sendLoop:
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        select {
        case ch <- i:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Printf("stopped\n")
            break sendLoop // Just exit the loop if something goes wrong (you may want to do something else here)
        }
    }
    close(ch) // Note: Important that this happens even if there is an error (otherwise `for n := range ch` may block, leaking goroutines)
    fmt.Printf("all sent\n")
    if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```